# Origin of the SEEV Model of visual attention distribution

Tags: reference-request, cognitive-modeling, vision, attention

What's the original source of the SEEV (Salience Effort Expectancy Value) Model for predicting the distribution of visual attention? I've seen it mentioned in many papers and presentations but everyone of them lacks a reference to the source of this model.

Does anyone have a valid reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wickens et al. (2003) is the earliest I'm aware of:

> Wickens, C. D., Goh, J., Helleberg, J., Horrey, W. J., & Talleur, D.
> A. (2003). Attentional models of multitask pilot performance using
> advanced display technology. Human Factors: The Journal of the Human
> Factors and Ergonomics Society, 45(3), 360-380.

Actually, in that paper he cites Wickens et al. (2001), but I can't seem to find
a copy of this manuscript anywhere, and it has fewer citations:

> Wickens, C. D., Helleberg, J., Goh, J., Xu, X., & Horrey, W. J.
> (2001). Pilot task management: Testing an attentional expected value
> model of visual scanning. Savoy, University of Illinois Institute of
> Aviation.

If you're using N-SEEV, cite one of these instead:

> Steelman-Allen, K. S., McCarley, J. S., Wickens, C., Sebok, A., &
> Bzostek, J. (2009, October). N-SEEV: A computational model of
> attention and noticing. In Proceedings of the Human Factors and
> Ergonomics Society Annual Meeting (Vol. 53, No. 12, pp. 774-778). SAGE
> Publications.
>
> Wickens, C., McCarley, J., & Steelman-Allen, K. (2009, October).
> NT-SEEV: A model of attention capture and noticing on the flight deck.
> In Proceedings of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society Annual
> Meeting (Vol. 53, No. 12, pp. 769-773). SAGE Publications.

Comment: honestly I didn't even know there were N- and NT-SEEV Models, thanks for that and the solid references. Couldn't have hoped for more

Answer (score 1):

Hi there had the same problem but i found the original report:

> Wickens, C. D., Helleberg, J., Goh, J., Xu, X., & Horrey, W. J.
>   (2001). Pilot Task Management: Testing an Attentional Expected Value
>   Model of Visual Scanning (Technical Report No. ARL-01-14/NASA-01-7).
>   NASA Ames Research Center. Retrieved from
>   http://www.aviation.illinois.edu/avimain/papers/research/pub_pdfs/techreports/01-14.pdf

enjoy!